# JavaFX call function on random created buttons

Tags: button, javafx, fxml

So, I am working on this school project where I created multiple buttons with text loaded from my database. These buttons are created everytime by listing a new button with another piece of text within it. I need my other function to be called while one of those buttons is being pressed.

The simple button function:

```
    public Button addOptionToSidebar(String Text)
    {
        optionSize++;
        Button optionButton = new Button();
        optionButton.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        optionButton.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
        optionButton.setText(Text);
        optionButton.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #fff; -fx-cursor: hand;");

        //Toevoegen aan sidebar
        CollectieSidebar.addRow(optionSize, optionButton);

        return optionButton;
    }
```

Everytime a button is being created, the function above is being called.

Comment: Yes @Calculuswhiz. I don't know what I was thinking at the time ahahah

Answer (score 0):

I feel extremely dumb for asking this. This issue is fixed of course by creating an onAction statement within the creation of each button.